# NullPointerException when using insertRow() ADF

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, oracle-adf

I am trying to add a record into a table in the database and I am getting `Nullpointerexception`

when executing the insert statement using `insertRow()`.

The Use-case:

The database table that I am trying to insert records in to it called `someTable`.

this table contain the following attributes: `A, B, C, D, E`

the primary key is a combination of three fields which are : `A, B, C`

I am executing the following code to insert new record in the table `someTable`:

```
    AppModuleImpl appModule = (AppModuleImpl)(JSFUtils.getApplicationModule("AppModuleDataControl"));

    ViewObject someTableVO =appModule.findViewObject("someTableView1");    

    Row row= someTableVO.createRow();

    row.setAttribute("A", varable1);
    row.setAttribute("B", varable2); 
    row.setAttribute("C", varable3);
    row.setAttribute("D", varable4);


    someTableVO.insertRow(row); // This statement cause the NullPointerException

    appModule.getDBTransaction().commit();

    someTableVO.executeQuery();
```

**Note:**

1. There is no `Not Null constrains` except for primary key of course, and I am adding data for all primary key fields which are ( `A`,`B` and `C` ).
2. I am not inserting data for filed `E` as you can see form the sample code above. But, even when I tried to add some value in to it, still gives me the same error.
3. I am sure that the variables ( `variable1` ...... `variable4`) are not `null`.
4. I am getting the right View object `someTableView1`
5. I am using `ADF` Technology with `Jdevelopr 11.1.2.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved

I should validate the row befor commit as follow:

```
    AppModuleImpl appModule = (AppModuleImpl)(JSFUtils.getApplicationModule("AppModuleDataControl"));  
    ViewObject someTableVO =appModule.findViewObject("someTableView1");          


    Row row= someTableVO.createRow();  

    row.setAttribute("A", variable1);  
    row.setAttribute("B", variable2);  
    row.setAttribute("C", variable3);  
    row.setAttribute("D", variable4);  



    someTableVO.insertRow(row); 

    row.validate();     // This statement solved the problem

    appModule.getDBTransaction().commit();  

    someTableVO.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible causes for a NullPointerException at that position:

1. someTableVO is NULL. ["Doublecheck that you have a view object instance in your datamodel named "someTableView1". It would return null if that were not defined."](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/434784)
2. Something in row is NULL. Your description sounds like you're not sure if the NPE is thrown at `someTableVO.insertRow(row)` or inside of it. What's the top source code position in the stack trace?

Debug it and tell us what is NULL.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful. it was your second point, I should validate the row before commit other wise it gives null pointer exception.